# is this foreach appropiate for adding text to a database or am i using the wrong method?

Tags: php, html

so i'm using a foreach loop to add into my MYSQL database the texts in the textareas tags, while it does work it shoves two separate rows, is there a way to add those texts in one row in PHP?
the html code:

```
<form method="POST"  action="echo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="text[]"></textarea><br><br>
    <textarea name="text[]"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="upl" value="send">
</form>
```

I've tried doing only the names without the [] and without the foreach, all it did was to only get the text from the second textarea completely ignoring the first one

the php code:

```
foreach($_POST['text'] as $text){
    $consult = $conection->prepare("INSERT INTO texts_form(description)
        VALUES('$text');");
    $consult->execute();
}
```

Comment: You are using `prepare()` but you are not parameterizing your query, so it's still vulnerable to SQL injection. The query should be `VALUES(?)` and then when you execute you should pass the variable, `execute([$text])`

Comment: You want the inputs from all textareas to be stored in a single cell? Why?

Comment: As noted above, you should use a parameter instead of directly inserting text into your query. However, I would go a step further and prepare the query before your loop, then just execute it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you prepare a query you can also parametise it. Then you only have to prepare the query once, but can run it with different parameters many times.

This means the database only has to Compile/Optimize  the query once, and the parameters are protected from SQL Injection attacks as well.

```
$stmt = $conection->prepare("INSERT INTO texts_form (description) VALUES(?)";

foreach($_POST['text'] as $text){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $text);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Or if you want the 2 fields in one row

```
$all .= $_POST['text'][0] . ' ' . $_POST['text'][1];

$stmt = $conection->prepare("INSERT INTO texts_form (description) VALUES(?)";
$stmt->bind_param('s', $all);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @pokemeta asks for getting "one row in PHP", which most likely means "one row in database".

Comment: @Anse I did not get that from my first reading of the question, thanks

Answer (score -2):

The [] turns your HTML response into an array. It sounds like you want to take the whole array, and turn it into a single string, and then put it into a single cell in your table, right?

So don't do an insert for each value, concatenate the values first, and then insert it once.

```
foreach($_POST['text'] as $text){
    $all_text .= $text ; 
}
```

Then sanitize $all_text and insert it.

Comment: This is a quite correct answer, why is it downvoted?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to save both/all textarea values in *one* database row, you should fire only *one* `INSERT` query, outside of a loop. For example you could concatenize all text values before inserting them:

```
$textVal = '';
foreach($_POST['text'] as $text){
    $textVal .= $text . "\n\n";
}
$consult = $conection->prepare("INSERT INTO texts_form(description)
    VALUES('$textVal');");
$consult->execute();
```

And of course you should care for single quotes in the text, which a parameterized query would do. Or something like this:

```
$consult = $conection->prepare("INSERT INTO texts_form(description)
    VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $textVal)."');");
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Security was not the key of the question - though I included a hint on that issue, didn't I? Why so rude?